# Terminal command 'edit' unknown (OSX 10.8.1) : -bash: edit: command not found

Tags: macos, terminal, text-editors

When I want to edit a file from within a terminal window, the edit command is not recognised.
I want it to open my editor (sublime text editor 2) and took the following steps:

Created a symbolic link on my path:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

specified it as my default editor:

```
export EDITOR='subl -w'
```

The command `subl` starts the editor up, so that worked fine. I can also see that the environment variable is set correctly.

But I stil get the "-bash: edit: command not found" error when trying to edit a file by entering `edit ~/.bashrc` for example.

Comment: Setting the `EDITOR` environment variable will just cause other (Unix-y) programs, e.g. `svn` or `git`, that require some kind of editing, to launch Sublime Text 2 instead of e.g. `vi`. If you're following a tutorial or manual, you're probably confusing the Windows and OS X parts.

Comment: When my collegues enter 'edit file.txt' it opens with a gui editor. When I do that I get the error as specified in the title. How do I make 'edit' open a gui text editor?

Comment: You did the same thing but with `subl`. Just rename the link you created in the first command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit is not a bash built-in command.

This means that the shell searches for a binary called `edit` in your `PATH` or an alias or a function called edit.